# Background color for Pageblock title

Tags: visualforce, css, pageblock

I have a visual force page which uses pageblock tag:

```
<apex:pageblock title="Sample">

</apex:pageblock>
```

I would like to make the background color of title="Sample" as green. How can I add styles to the pageblock tag. I tried tabstyle but seems like it does not serve the purpose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't see a Salesforce supported way of doing this. But for a little bit hacking into this you can use the below css code which is working for me:

```
body .bPageBlock .pbHeader {
    background-color: Green; 
}
```

You don't need to add an class or attributes in your html for using this.

Comment: Thanks. What if I don't have a html tag in my code. Is it still doable? Any Hack for that?

Comment: Sorry , I tried and it worked with out <html> tags. THanks